# Show FPS in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate

I'm working on a project with my friend in python with pygame. We have tried to make an FPS counter in our game but we haven't succeeded. The FPS counter is always displaying a zero. Here is the code:

```
#Create Text
def Render_Text(what, color, where):
    font = pygame.font.Font('assets/Roboto.ttf', 30)
    text = font.render(what, 1, pygame.Color(color))
    window.blit(text, where)
```

```
#Show FPS
    Render_Text(str(int(clock.get_fps())), (255,0,0), (0,0))
    print("FPS:", int(clock.get_fps()))
```

Comment: is `clock` = `pygame.time.Clock()`?

Comment: Yes, clock is pygame.time.Clock()

Comment: Do you call `clock.tick()` once per frame?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`get_fps()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.get_fps) only gives a correct result, when you call [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) once per frame:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False          

    clock.tick()
    print(clock.get_fps())

    # [...]
```

See the documentation of [`get_fps()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.get_fps)

> `get_fps()` compute the clock framerate
>
> `get_fps() -> float`
>
> Compute your game's framerate (in frames per second). It is computed by averaging the last ten calls to `Clock.tick()`.

Answer (score 4):

Initialize your clock

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

Add your font

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial" , 18 , bold = True)
```

And your fps function

```
def fps_counter():
    fps = str(int(clock.get_fps()))
    fps_t = font.render(fps , 1, pygame.Color("RED"))
    window.blit(fps_t,(0,0))
```

Call your function in loop

```
fps_counter()
#dont forget to add tick(60) to run 60 frame per sec
```